# Does $\Sigma_1 \cup \Pi_1$ generate the complete first order theory of arithmetic?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, peano-axioms

If a set $T$ of sentences in the language of arithmetic

- is deductively closed under the usual inference rules of first order logic, and
- includes all true $\Sigma_1$ sentences and all true $\Pi_1$ sentences, and
- includes no false sentences;

is $T$ necessarily the complete first-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: This question just has a problem statement, without any background information (where did you encounter the problem, what else do you already know) and without any description of what you have tried. That additional information is important for people who try to answer the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The set $T$ is computable in $0''$. The theory of $\mathbb{N}$ contains the entire [arithmetical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). Therefore $T$ can't be the theory of $\mathbb{N}$.

In response to the comment I'll show how to construct a sentence that is independent of $T$. There might be a better way, but this is the easiest that I can see.

$T$ is computably enumerable in $0'$, so by [Post's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem) there is a $\Sigma_2$ formula $\phi(x)$ such that for any sentence $\psi$, $\mathbb{N} \models \phi(\ulcorner \psi \urcorner)$ if and only if $\psi \in T$. Then, I think the proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem still applies using $\phi$ as a provability predicate, so we can construct a sentence independent of $T$ by diagonalization.

Comment: It is the second [Turing jump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump) of the empty set (ie $0^{(2)}$ in the linked article).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see Andreas' answer before editing, never mind.

Answer (score 8):

The consistency of $T$ is a true arithmetical sentence yet is not provable in $T$.  This observation depends on two well-known facts:  First, one can define, in the language of arithmetic, the notion of a "true $\Sigma_1$ or $\Pi_1$ sentence".  (In fact, although there is no arithmetical truth definition for the entire language of arithmetic, there are truth definitions for any bounded part of the arithmetical hierarchy.)  So one can define what $T$ is and then formalize "$T$ is consistent" in the language of arithmetic.  Second, Gödel's second incompleteness theorem (about the unprovability of consistency), though often stated only for recursively axiomatized theories, can be extended to more general arithmetically definable theories like $T$.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Forgive my ignorance, but why is $T$ not $\Pi_1$? I thought sentences of the form, "so and so is consistent" were always $\Pi_1$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, why is the statement "$T$ is consistent" not $\Pi_1$.

Comment: Because it refers to the truth definition for $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences, which requires additional quantifiers. Consistency statements for effective theories are $\Pi^0_1$ but the theory in question is not effective.  You should review the construction of the Gödel sentence and see where the complexity of the theory affects the complexity of the consistency statement.

Comment: Could you give a reference for the claim that Gödel's second incompleteness theorem can be extended to arithmetically definable theories? 

I believe the assumption that $T$ be $\Sigma^0_1$ is best possible in the arithmetical hierarchy, i.e. that there are consistent $\Pi^0_1$ theories $T$ containing PA for which both Con$(T)$ and Pf$_T($Con$(T))$ hold.

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze I believe the correct relativization of Gödel’s theorem is that if $T$ is a consistent $\Sigma_{n+1}$-axiomatized theory that *proves all true $\Pi_n$ sentences*, then $T$ cannot prove its own consistency (formalized using a natural $\Sigma_{n+1}$ provability predicate).

Comment: More precisely, the $\Sigma_{n+1}$ provability predicate should explicitly allow arbitrary true $\Pi_n$ axioms. This is all to make $\mathrm{Pr}_T(\phi)\to\mathrm{Pr}_T(\mathrm{Pr}_T(\phi))$ provable. One can drop the assumption on provability of true $\Pi_n$ sentences by formulating it as follows: if $T$ is a $\Sigma_n$-sound $\Sigma_{n+1}$-axiomatized theory, then $T$ cannot prove its own $\Sigma_n$-soundness (i.e., the uniform $\Sigma_n$-reflection principle).